# With `pandas.cut()`, how do I get integer bins and avoid getting a negative lowest bound?

Tags: python, pandas, intervals, bins

My dataframe has zero as the lowest value. I am trying to use the `precision` and `include_lowest` parameters of `pandas.cut()`, but I can't get the intervals consist of integers rather than floats with one decimal. I can also not get the left most interval to stop at zero.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style='white', font_scale=1.3)

df = pd.DataFrame(range(0,389,8)[:-1], columns=['value'])
df['binned_df_pd'] = pd.cut(df.value, bins=7, precision=0, include_lowest=True)
sns.pointplot(x='binned_df_pd', y='value', data=df)
plt.xticks(rotation=30, ha='right')
```

[image]

I have tried setting `precision` to -1, 0 and 1, but they all output one decimal floats. The `pandas.cut()` help does mention that the x-min and x-max values are extended with 0.1 % of the x-range, but I thought maybe `include_lowest` could suppress this behaviour somehow. My current workaround involves importing numpy:

```
import numpy as np

bin_counts, edges = np.histogram(df.value, bins=7)
edges = [int(x) for x in edges]
df['binned_df_np'] = pd.cut(df.value, bins=edges, include_lowest=True)

sns.pointplot(x='binned_df_np', y='value', data=df)
plt.xticks(rotation=30, ha='right')
```

[image]

Is there a way to obtain non-negative integers as the interval boundaries directly with `pandas.cut()` without using numpy?

**Edit:** I just noticed that specifying `right=False` makes the lowest interval shift to 0 rather than -0.4. It seems to take precedence over `include_lowest`, as changing the latter does not have any visible effect in combination with `right=False`. The following intervals are still specified with one decimal point.

[image]

Comment: A proposal to fix this behavior: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/47996

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the other answers (including OP's `np.histogram` workaround) seem to work anymore. They have upvotes, so I'm not sure if something has changed over the years.

`IntervalIndex` requires all intervals to be closed identically, so `[0, 53]` cannot coexist with `(322, 376]`.

---

Here are two working solutions based on the relabeling approach:

1. **Without numpy,** reuse `pd.cut` edges as `pd.cut` labels

   ```py
   bins = 7

   _, edges = pd.cut(df.value, bins=bins, retbins=True)
   labels = [f'({abs(edges[i]):.0f}, {edges[i+1]:.0f}]' for i in range(bins)]

   df['bin'] = pd.cut(df.value, bins=bins, labels=labels)

   #     value         bin
   # 1       8     (0, 53]
   # 2      16     (0, 53]
   # ..    ...         ...
   # 45    360  (322, 376]
   # 46    368  (322, 376]
   ```
2. **With numpy,** convert `np.linspace` edges into `pd.cut` labels

   ```py
   bins = 7

   edges = np.linspace(df.value.min(), df.value.max(), bins+1).astype(int)
   labels = [f'({edges[i]}, {edges[i+1]}]' for i in range(bins)]

   df['bin'] = pd.cut(df.value, bins=bins, labels=labels)

   #     value         bin
   # 1       8     (0, 53]
   # 2      16     (0, 53]
   # ..    ...         ...
   # 45    360  (322, 376]
   # 46    368  (322, 376]
   ```

*Note: Only the labels are changed, so the underlying binning will still occur with 0.1% margins.*

---

`pointplot()` output (as of pandas 1.2.4):

```
sns.pointplot(x='bin', y='value', data=df)
plt.xticks(rotation=30, ha='right')
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

you should specifically set the `labels` argument

#### preparations:

```
lower, higher = df['value'].min(), df['value'].max()
n_bins = 7
```

#### build up the labels:

```
edges = range(lower, higher, (higher - lower)/n_bins) # the number of edges is 8
lbs = ['(%d, %d]'%(edges[i], edges[i+1]) for i in range(len(edges)-1)]
```

#### set labels:

```
df['binned_df_pd'] = pd.cut(df.value, bins=n_bins, labels=lbs, include_lowest=True)
```

Comment: Will this work if `(higher-lower)/n_bins ` is not an integer?

Answer (score 3):

@joelostblom, you did most of the work already, instead of using numpy,
just use what pandas already provide, which is returning bins.

```
_, edges = pd.cut(df.value, bins=7, retbins=True)
edges = [int(x) for x in edges]
df['binned_df_np'] = pd.cut(df.value, bins=edges, include_lowest=True)
```